# How to sum up the number under the category

Tags: python, plotly

I want to  sum up the number which are under the same category. I'm only able to sum up for 1 group and unable to sum up for the rest of the groups.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Revenue.csv')
fig = px.bar(df,x='year', y='amount', color='class',height=400, width=700, title="Revenue")

# create a new column as `lump_sump`
df['lump_sum'] = df['amount']

df_groupby= df.groupby(["class","year"])["amount"]


for name,group in df_groupby:
    class_cat, year_cat =  name
    df.loc[group.index.tolist(),'lump_sum'] = group.sum()
     fig.update_traces(customdata=df[(df['class']==class_cat)] 
    ['lump_sum'],hovertemplate='class:'+class_cat+' <br>year: %{x} <br>amount: %{y} 
    Lump Sum: %{customdata:0.2f}',selector={'name':class_cat})

fig.show()
```

[image: Ouput]

I'm able to sum up those in green but unable to do so for those in blue or red. Kindly advise if there is any error with my code.

Comment: You can simplify your code to `group.loc[:, "lump_sum"] = group.sum(). Are you sure there are no issues with your data? In the plot it looks like the groups are all summed up, and the green group just has higher numbers.